# "should have taken" vs "should've had taken", are they both correct?

Tags: past-tense, should, have

So my friend and I were talking earlier today, he clicked away from a website, and I said:

> You should've had taken a screenshot of those results.

To which he replied:

> What? You mean I "Should've taken" a screenshot?

And then we argued if "should've had" is correct or not. I feel like not only is "should've had" correct, but it also has a slightly different meaning than "should have".

Can someone help us out?

Comment: Either _You should've had a screenshot_ or _You should've taken a screenshot_ is OK. No difference. But not *_You should've had taken a screenshot_.

Comment: You can say _You should have had [a noun]_, where the second _have_ is the main verb, but you can't say _you should have had [done something]_, where both are auxiliary verbs.

Answer (score 1):

*This* version is correct:

> You should've **had a screenshot taken** of those results.

Compare it to: "he should've had his car fixed by now."

As is your friend's version, though it means something different:

> You **should've taken a screenshot** of those results.

Compare it to: "he should've fixed his car by now."

But the word order in your version ("should've had taken") is wrong, or at least very unidiomatic. It would be like saying: "he should've had fixed his car by now."